# How to update parameter value from excel file on each simulation day in Anylogic

Tags: excel, anylogic

I am working on a model in which I have a parameter called supply. This parameter should change on a daily basis as I have a different supply amount of raw materials each day. I am using an excel file containing a column called supply and 10 rows (supply values for 10 days).

My question is how can I use this excel file as input and have the model read the first row on day one, 2nd row on day 2, etc? Updating the parameter on each simulation day.

I am using the Anylogic personal learning edition.

Answer (score 0):

1. Loop across all dbase entries at the start of the model (using the database query wizard, choose option "iterate over returned rows and do something").
2. for each row, compute the duration from model start to what the row represents
3. for each row, create a Dynamic Event (on Main or wherever) using `create_MyDynamicEvent(x, HOUR)` where x is the duration from point 2 above, in hrs. Give it an argument `quantity` and provide the current row's value
4. in the Dynamic Event, you change your parameter with the value provided, i.e. `set_myParam(value)`

You can also use a schedule or a source to do this, but the approach would be quite different.

Comment: Apparently I can't use the database query wizard because I am using the personal learning edition. Is there another way to loop across the DB ?

Comment: Use the code directly: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/querying.html